# How to refer to a variable(start with number) defined in the application.yml file with @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my application.yml has this:

```
company:
  core:
    3rd:
#     Other variable...
```

My config file:

```
@Configuration("companyProperties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "company", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class CompanyProperties {
    //jhipster-needle-application-properties-property
    private final CoreProperties core = new CoreProperties();
    // other fields ...
    //jhipster-needle-application-properties-property-getter
    //getter and setter ...
    //jhipster-needle-application-properties-property-class

    // Nested class for Core properties
    public static class CoreProperties {
        @JsonProperty("3rd")
        private final ThirdPartyProperties third = new ThirdPartyProperties();
        //...

        public ThirdPartyProperties getThird() {
            return third;
        }
    }

    // Nested class for Third Party properties
    public static class ThirdPartyProperties {
    // some fields, getter and setter
    }

}
```

And I faced this error:

```
Property: company.core.3rd.[other_variables_inside_3rd...]__    Value: ""__    Origin: class path resource [config/application.yml] - 555:12__    Reason: The elements [company.core.3rd.[other_variables_inside_3rd...] were left unbound
```

I think because property in class config cannot refer to "3rd" in application.yml file.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Renaming the property is the most sensible solution.